# Convex description of the positive orthant without the y-axis

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, convex-geometry

I know that the following set is convex
\begin{equation}
X = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x>0 ,~ y\geq0 \}~ \cup~\{(0,0)\}
\end{equation}
i.e. the positive orthant without the y-axis but with the origin, and I am wondering if it is possible to describe this set with a finite (or infinite) number of convex constraints on $x$ and $y$ ?